# Pullback along the Frobenius morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, quasicoherent-sheaves, algebraic-k-theory, positive-characteristic

Let $X$ be a scheme over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and let $F : X \to X$ be the absolute Frobenius morphism. If $\mathcal{L}$ is an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then $F^*(\mathcal{L}) \cong \mathcal{L}^{\otimes q}$ (naturally in $\mathcal{L}$).

> Is there also a general formula for $F^*(\mathcal{M})$ if $\mathcal{M}$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of given rank $d$?

In other words, I ask for a bundle representative  of the Adams operation $\psi^q$ on the $K$-theory of $X$. For example, when $q=2$, we have $\psi^2(x)=x^2-2 \lambda^2(x)$, and one could hope for a representation of $F^*(\mathcal{M})$ as the cokernel of some monomorphism $\Lambda^2(\mathcal{M}) \oplus \Lambda^2(\mathcal{M}) \to \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{M}$, or as the kernel of some epimorphism $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{M} \to \Lambda^2(\mathcal{M}) \oplus \Lambda^2(\mathcal{M})$.

Comment: You've probably already thought about this, but in terms of Čech data we can describe $F^*(\mathcal M)$ as the bundle whose transition matrix is the entry-wise $p$-th power of that of $\mathcal M$. We want to understand the effect on $H^1$ of the map $\operatorname{GL}_n \to \operatorname{GL}_n$ given by entry-wise $p$-th power. I do not know how to do this for $n > 1$.

Comment: Yes, I also do not know how to obtain a global description out of these gluing data.

Comment: Meanwhile, it has been answered on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224075